# Using jQuery iterate in images inside div and change their src and also add one new attribute

Tags: jquery

each div has one image having fixed class. i need to change all images src inside those div which has class called ".**diagnostic_picture**" using jquery and also add one new attribute to all the images called "**delaySrc**" inside that div having class called ".diagnostic_picture". here this way wrote the code but did not work....can anyone help me. thanks

```
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test1.gif" /></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test2.gif" /></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test3.gif" /></div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".diagnostic_picture").each(function () {
            $(this).children("img")
            .attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif')       // this way i change the src
            .attr('delaySrc', $this.attr("src")); ;      // this way i add new attribute
        });
    });
```

the attribute called **delaySrc** not being added to img tag inside the div so i change the code bit but still new attribute not being added....i check source by firebug.

### change code

```
  $(".diagnostic_picture img").each(function () {
        var img = $(this);
        img.attr("delaySrc", function () { img.attr("src") })
        img.attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif');
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't start a class name with a `.` character - it must start with an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct version of your code (note both the changes in html makrup - class values do not need prefix dot, and in javascipt)

```
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test1.gif" ></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test2.gif" ></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test3.gif" ></div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".diagnostic_picture img").attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif').attr('delaySrc', function() { $(this).attr("src") });
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for code....you code works partially it change all images src but code fail to add new attribute called "delaySrc" to all images inside div having class called "diagnostic_picture". so please look at ur code & do rectify it to add new attribute to all images. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".diagnostic_picture").children()
            .attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif')       // this way i change the src
            .attr('delaySrc', $this.attr("src")); ;      // this way i add new attribute
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for code....you code works partially it change all images src but code fail to add new attribute called "delaySrc" to all images inside div having class called "diagnostic_picture". so please look at ur code & do rectify it to add new attribute to all images. thanks

Comment: @Thomas  since delaySrc may be not a standard attribute so instead of delaysrc use data-* attributes of html5

Answer (score 1):

just remove this block `$(document).ready(function () {})` for realy preload

```
$(".diagnostic_picture img")
        .attr('delaySrc', function(){return $(this).attr("src");})
        .attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif');
```

Comment: thanks for code....you code works partially it change all images src but code fail to add new attribute called "delaySrc" to all images inside div having class called "diagnostic_picture". so please look at ur code & do rectify it to add new attribute to all images. thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove dots form class names:

```
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test1.gif" ></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test2.gif" ></div>
<div class="diagnostic_picture"><img src="test3.gif" ></div>
```

and you should change `$this` to `$(this)`, also you can use `data-` for having valid attributes:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".diagnostic_picture img").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", 'images/ajax-loader.gif')       // changing src
            .attr('data-delaySrc', $(this).attr("src")); ;      // you can use 'data-' for having a valid attribute
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for code....you code works partially it change all images src but code fail to add new attribute called "delaySrc" to all images inside div having class called "diagnostic_picture". so please look at ur code & do rectify it to add new attribute to all images. thanks